# Advantages of having applications from Anaconda or independent (and the latest)

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, rstudio, orange

Can someone can explain and advise whether and why one should install and use applications such as Orange or RStudio or VS Code from Anaconda vs. download and install directly/independently (as stand-alone apps)? At a minimum, what I see (as I am using RStudio and VS Code) current stable versions on the internet are (much) newer.

I am using:

```
      conda version : 4.8.1
conda-build version : 3.18.9
     python version : 3.7.4.final.0
           platform : osx-64
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware all that installing VSCode from Anaconda does is pre-install the "Anaconda Extension Pack", which inturn is just a meta-package for VSCode's Python and YAML extensions. You could install VSCode independently and install those 2 extensions and you'd have basically the same setup (when you launch it for the first time, you may have to manually select your conda environment in VSCode).

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda pre-installed a lot of packages for you, so you don't have to install them manually. Anaconda create an environment in VSCode, so when you need to use these packages, you have to start VSCode from Anaconda, or switch to `conda` environment.

On the other hand, when using VSCode independently, you have to install packages yourself.